# PHPUnit replaces the path passed to the visit function

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with PHPUnit 4 and wrote myself some tests. They are all successful except for one.

```
public function testCostTypeEdit()
{
    $role = factory(\Bican\Roles\Models\Role::class)->create();
    $user = factory(\App\Model\User::class)->create();
    $user->attachRole($role);

    $costType = factory(\App\Model\CostType::class)->create();

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('admin/reservations')
        ->see(trans('strings.costType'))
        ->see($costType->description)
        ->type(15, $costType->slug)
        ->press(trans('strings.save'))
        ->see(trans('messages.costType'));
}
```

This test always fails and I get this error

```
1) AdminReservationTest::testCostTypeEdit
A request to [http://localhost/admin.cars] failed. Received status code [404].

C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:178
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:72
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:120
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:72
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:53
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\tests\AdminReservationTest.php:94
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
```

As you can see the test fails because he trys to visit 'admin.cars'. There are two problems with that:
First I don't have a route called 'admin.cars' I only have 'admin/cars' therefor the 404.
Seconed that isn't even the path I passed to the visit function.

I have 3 other tests for 'admin/reservation' that look identical to the one above. I copied one of them and replaced everything inside of testCostTypeEdit() and the test worked. When I change even one line it fails with the same error again.

When I pass him the path to any other route I have it isn't replaced and I don't get the 404 error.

When I pass him a non-existing path like 'adminreservations' it isn't replaced either

```
1) AdminReservationTest::testCostTypeEdit
A request to [http://localhost/adminreservations] failed. Received status code [404].

C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:178
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:72
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:53
C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\tests\AdminReservationTest.php:94
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
```

I don't know what I should try anymore.
Does anyone of you have an idea why this happens?
If you need some more information I'm happy to give it to you.

Comment: Dump the products of the factory()->create() calls to make sure you're not hitting some unexpected middleware, especially if role can be rejected for this route under some circumstances. Run this test in isolation and check build/coverage/index.html to see what code is being covered, and where it's redirecting in an unexpected way. Follow that path (into Laravel core files probably) with dd() to find the real cause. Which could be a Laravel/PHPUnit bug, but might not be

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found the problem and feel kinda stupid right now. I forgot one factory()->create() call and so one object was missing. My controller should have redirected to 'admin/cars' but I accidentally put a dot there instead of a slash. Thats where the 'admin.cars' came from.

Comment: grep would have been a good suggestion too, but anyway. +1 my comment if it helped, but I wont do a full answer in the circumstances.

Comment: I would, but I can't upvote yet.

Comment: Nmind - not a big deal :)